# troubles with vb net, mysql and entity framework 6 sbyte type

Tags: mysql, vb.net, entity-framework

I've defined a project in visual studio 2015, I've used ADO NET Code first to connect with a mysql database (mysql connector 6.9.9), and now, having the model, I'm trying to use entity framework 6.

I've installed from nuget 'mysql entity framework 6.9.9' in my project, but when I try to connect with the model, next message is shown:

> SBYTE THERE IS NO STORE TYPE Corresponding to the conceptual side type
>   'SBYTE' of primitive type 'SBYTE'

.Net framework 4.5.2

Any suggest??

Thanks!!

Comment: Your server might not support the datatype. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39520364/832052, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28992215/832052, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/15567178/832052

Answer (score 0):

SByte is not a data type supported by the providers (at least is not supported by SQL Server, SQL Server CE, Microsoft Access, MySQL).
If you Really Want a class with an SByte, the best way is to use a [private] backing and expose the SByte property.
This is the model for a private backing field.

```
public class Info
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public sbyte SByte
    {
        get
        {
            return (sbyte) SByteBackingField;
        }
        set
        {
            SByteBackingField = value;
        }
    }


    private int SByteBackingField { get; set; }


    public class InfoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Info>
    {
        public InfoMap()
        {
            ToTable("Infoes69");
            Property(_ => _.SByteBackingField).HasColumnName("SByte");
            Ignore(_ => _.SByte);
        }
    }

}
```

and in context you need to add the configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Info.InfoMap());
}
```

The issue is that **you can't use SByte property in queries**.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this when using MySQL because EntityFramework defaults to using SQL Server - which does not have this data type.

The solution (for me) had 2 parts, either of which caused the same error:

1. Go into Web.Config, and set the correct provider for entity framework

   ```
    <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
   ```
2. Make sure that the connection string was set properly.

YMMV!